# Making http/https file sharing server for Android Download Manager

Tags: java, android, file-upload

I'm using **Download Manager on Android** side to download files from different sources. Now I should to create a **server side** for this application.

First of all here is the simple code for the Android side:

```
private DownloadManager mgr = null;
private long lastDownload = -1L;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mgr = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    registerReceiver(onNotificationClick, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unregisterReceiver(onComplete);
    unregisterReceiver(onNotificationClick);

}

public void startDownload(View v) {
    // Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://commonsware.com/misc/test.mp4");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/FileUpload/asd.mp3");

    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).mkdirs();

    lastDownload = mgr.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
            .setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                    DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("Demo")
            .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "test.mp4"));

    v.setEnabled(false);
    findViewById(R.id.query).setEnabled(true);
}

public void queryStatus(View v) {
    Cursor c = mgr.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(lastDownload));

    if (c == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Download not found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        c.moveToFirst();

        Log.d(getClass().getName(),
                "COLUMN_ID: " + c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_ID)));
        Log.d(getClass().getName(),
                "COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR: "
                        + c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR)));
        Log.d(getClass().getName(),
                "COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP: "
                        + c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP)));
        Log.d(getClass().getName(),
                "COLUMN_LOCAL_URI: " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI)));
        Log.d(getClass().getName(),
                "COLUMN_STATUS: " + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)));
        Log.d(getClass().getName(),
                "COLUMN_REASON: " + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON)));

        Toast.makeText(this, statusMessage(c), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void viewLog(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
}

private String statusMessage(Cursor c) {
    String msg = "???";

    switch (c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))) {
    case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
        msg = "Download failed!";
        break;

    case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
        msg = "Download paused!";
        break;

    case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
        msg = "Download pending!";
        break;

    case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
        msg = "Download in progress!";
        break;

    case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
        msg = "Download complete!";
        break;

    default:
        msg = "Download is nowhere in sight";
        break;
    }

    return (msg);
}

BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        findViewById(R.id.start).setEnabled(true);
    }
};

BroadcastReceiver onNotificationClick = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Ummmm...hi!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

As you can see I tryed to use it. If I put some files into a **WebProject -> WebContent** **than I can download it**. But I would need to access all files in the server computer. (I think that I should use a servlet which can handle the Download Manager's request and can upload somehow the file, but Im not sure of it.) The Android's **Download Manager** can handle only **HTTP and HTTPS.**

I would implement the server side, but I really don't know how to do it, so the question is: **How can I implement a right server side which can serve the Download Manager's request.**

Thank you if you can help you.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: I would implement the server side, but I really don't know how to do it, so the question is: How can I implement a right server side which can serve the Download Manager's request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution for my problem BUT I want to say THANK YOU for your answer!

The simple solution:

```
    File f = new File("d:\\....");
    int length = 0;
    ServletOutputStream op = response.getOutputStream();
    ServletContext context = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
    String mimetype = context.getMimeType("d:\\Zene\\WakaWaka.mp3");

    //
    // Set the response and go!
    //
    //
    response.setContentType((mimetype != null) ? mimetype : "application/octet-stream");
    response.setContentLength((int) f.length());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "seven-eurotura.cd1.avi" + "\"");

    //
    // Stream to the requester.
    //
    byte[] bbuf = new byte[100];
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));

    while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
        op.write(bbuf, 0, length);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a web service. You can use a framework like [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) to handle download request. The request can contain path / query parameters that can help the service determine which file the client wants. It can also provide auth in several ways.

As for the backend, you can save the files to a common disk if reliability is not a matter of concern. Alternatively you can save the file using a network storage device. You can also upload it to a third party like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and simply provide the download link of the file to the client. So the service would act as way to discover the download links. It would not host the files itself.

Take your pick.